# Rounding a float upward to an integer, how reliable is that?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I've seen `static_cast<int>(std::ceil(floatValue));` before.

My question though, is can I absolutely count on this not "needlessly" rounding up?  I've read that some whole numbers can't be perfectly represented in floating point, so my worry is that the miniscule "error" will trick `ceil()` into rounding upwards when it logically shouldn't.  Not only that, but once rounded up, I worry it may be possible for a small "error" in representation to cause the number to be slightly less than a whole number, causing the cast to int to truncate it.

Is this worry unfounded?  I remember a while back, an example in python where printing a specific whole number would cause it to print something very slightly less (like x.999, though I can't remember the exact number)

The reason I need to make sure, is I'm writing a texture buffer.  The common case is whole numbers as floating point, but it'll occasionally get between values that need to be rounded to the nearest integer width and height that contains them.  It increments in steps of power of 2, so the cost of rounding up needlessly can cause what should've only took a 256x256 texture to need a 512x512 texture.

Comment: It depends on the range of `floatValue`. What *is* the range?

Comment: The range is 0.0 to ~1024.0 (I don't think I'll need to worry of values beyond that range)

Comment: The integers that can't be represented as floats will be rounded to another integer (a multiple of some power of two), not to some fraction slightly below or above the integer. However, some arithmetic which would (for real numbers) result in an integer may result in slightly less or more than an integer. That, however, is independent of how you round it as it happens beforehand.

Comment: @delnan - I did not know this at all.  The origin of the floats in the common case, is they are cast from an `int`.  Knowing that the small errors are sourced from arithmetic, and not from just how they are represented, puts me a lot more at ease with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I absolutely count on this not "needlessly" rounding up? I've read that some whole numbers can't be perfectly represented in floating point, so my worry is that the miniscule "error" will trick ceil()

Yes, some large numbers are impossible to represent exactly as floating-point numbers. In the zone where this happens, all floating-point numbers are integers. The error is not minuscule: the error in representing an integer by a floating-point, if error there is, is at least one. And, obviously, in the zone where some integers cannot be represented as floating-point and where all floating-point numbers are integers, `ceil(f) == f`.

The zone in question is |f| > 2<sup>24</sup> (16*1024*1024) for IEEE 754 single-precision and |f| > 2<sup>53</sup> for IEEE 754 double-precision.

A problem you are more likely to come across does not come from the impossibility of representing integers in floating-point format but from the cumulative effects of rounding errors. If your compiler offers IEEE 754 (the floating-point standard implemented exactly by the SSE2 instructions of modern and not so modern Intel processors) semantics, then any +, -, *, / and sqrt operation that results in a number exactly representable as floating-point is guaranteed to produce that result, but if several of the operations you apply do not have exactly representable results, the floating-point computation may drift away from the mathematical computation, even when the final result is an integer and is exactly representable. Then you may end up with a floating-point result slightly above the target integer and cause `ceil()` to return something other than you would have obtained with exact mathematical computations.

There are ways to be confident that some floating-point operations are exact (because the result is always representable). For instance `(double)float1 * (double)float2`, where `float1` and `float2` are two single-precision variables, is always exact, because the mathematical result of the multiplication of two single-precision numbers is always representable as a `double`. By doing the computation the “right” way, it is possible to minimize or eliminate the error in the end result.

Answer (score 4):

If `floatValue` is exact, then there is no problem with rounding in your code. The only possible problem is overflow (if the result doesn't fit inside an `int`). Of course with such large values, the `float` will typically not have enough precision to distinguish adjacent integers anyway.

However, the danger usually lies in `floatValue` itself not being exact. For example, if it is the result of some computation whose exact answer is a whole number, it may end up a tiny amount greater than a whole number due to floating point rounding errors in the computation.

So whether you have a problem depends on how you got `floatValue`.

Answer (score 2):

> The range is 0.0 to ~1024.0

All integers in this range can be represented exactly as `float`, so you'll be fine.

You'll only start having issues once you stray beyond the [24 bits of mantissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary32) afforded by `float`.

Comment: But those issues will revolve around integers turning into other integers, not in 5 billion becoming 5 billion point nine nine nine and so on.